# JAPE double negation handling

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to prove a simple conjecture using JAPE application. There must be some 'magic trick' in JAPE to get rid of double negation statements but I have no idea how to handle it properly. The point where it all makes sens to me is:

[image]

I have started from line 5 and then going backwards I did implication intro twice. Could anyone (who knows JAPE) tell me how to get --E to E and from --F to F so the implication E -> F holds?

EDIT:

After Mauro's suggestions I'm at the point were I have a contradiction but JAPE still wants smth more in it:

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the answer 'double negation elimination' is not available in JAPE, I guess it must be replaced with some other steps.

Answer (score 0):

The 'magic trick' in the *Natural Deduction* proof is to use [Double Negation elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation) rule :

> $\lnot \lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi$.

If not available, you must have a "contradiction" rules; see : Richard Bornat, [Proof and Disproof in Formal Logic : An Introduction for Programmers](https://books.google.it/books?id=PxbY_jIMdVEC) (2005), that is a reference for [Jape software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jape_(software)), page 43 :

> if $\Gamma \vdash \bot$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ --- contradiction (constructive)

and :

> if $\Gamma, \lnot \varphi \vdash \bot$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ --- contradiction (classical).

---

In this case, they are not necessary :

The derivation is :

1) $E \to F$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \lnot E$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot F$ --- assumed [b]

4) $E$ --- assumed [c]

5) $F$ --- from 1) and 4) by $\to$-elimination

6) $\bot$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\lnot$-elimination

7) $\lnot E$ --- from 4) and 6) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [c]

8) $\bot$ from 2) and 7) by $\lnot$-elim

9) $\lnot \lnot F$ --- from 3) and 8) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [b]

> 10) $\lnot \lnot E \to \lnot \lnot F$ --- from 2) and 9) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

Comment: I know the double negation elimination rule, the point is that its not available in JAPE.

Comment: pls see my edit where I've posted new image, it looks like JAPE has some peculiar own rules to solve this and even if your solution looks ok to me I cannot translate it directly into JAPE interface/commands.

Comment: Hey @Mauro, still no luck, I really appreciate your efforts, the problem is with putting your proof to JAPE itself, it just cannot be done in a form you posted.